# Why $I = [0,1]$ is a $1$-manifold and $I^2$ not?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, manifolds

I am stuck in this, I have no idea why!
$[0,1]$ is a manifold with boundary, how to justify? Which are the charts?
And how about $[0,1]^2?$ Why it is not a manifold?

My definition of topological manifold with or without boundary is the usual.

Comment: $[0,1]^2$ **is** a topological manifold with boundary, but it is **not** a $1$-manifold.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your definition of a manifold with boundary.

Comment: Thanks @Omnomnomnom, I will include, could you justify after that?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It is not a topological manifold. It has boundary points with neighborhoods homeomorphic to half spaces rather than $R^2$. Just to be pedantic about manifolds vs manifolds with boundary. Also when you do smooth then it has a corner because the wedge can be straightened but not smoothly.

Comment: I think $I^2$ would then be a $2$-manifold with boundary if I'm not mistaken, under most definitions.

Comment: @AHusain thanks, I actually was a bit shaky on the definition apparently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But it **is** a manifold with boundary. More precisely, $[0,1]^2$ is a topological space, and as a topological space it is homeomorphic to $D^2 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \|x\| \le 1 \}$. You probably already know that $D^2$ can be equipped with charts that make it into a smooth manifold with boundary, and you can transport these charts through the homeomorphism to make $[0,1]^2$ into a smooth manifold with boundary.

However, $[0,1]^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a smooth embedded **sub**manifold with boundary. Whatever smooth charts you will put on $[0,1]^2$ to make it into a submanifold, the inclusion $i : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ will not be an embedding.

The problem is at the corners, say $(0,0)$. If $i$ were smooth, then the restriction of $i$ to the boundary would be smooth too. From the topology, we know what the boundary would be: when one of the coordinates is $0$ or $1$.

But then, the differential of $i$ when restricted to $\{0\} \times (0,\epsilon)$ would be proportional to a vertical tangent vector in the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^2$, whereas the differential when restricted to $(0,\epsilon) \times \{0\}$ would be proportional to a horizontal vector. Since the differential has to be continuous, this is a contradiction as the differential at $(0,0)$ would have be at the same time horizontal and vertical, hence would be the zero vector; but an embedding has to be an immersion.

Comment: I just want to clarify that, to be totally pedantic, it depends on your starting data. Yes, as a topological space, $I^2$ can be endowed with a smooth structure in this way, but if you want to carry an "atlas" you get on $I^2$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can only get a manifold with corners. In summary, you have to throw out the old atlas and get a new one, so it depends on if that is part of your starting data.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi you can carry a smooth structure with a homeomorphism? Don't you need it to be smooth also?

Comment: @LuisVera What does it mean to be "smooth" if the other space isn't a smooth manifold already? If $X$ is a topological space, homeomorphic to $Y$, and $Y$ has a smooth atlas, then you can use the homeomorphism to transport the atlas and make $X$ into a smooth manifold too. Then the homeomorphism becomes automatically smooth, by definition.

Comment: There is a perfectly valid notion of smoothness for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Actually more than one.) For example, say $f:I^2 \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth if $f$ extends to a smooth function on a neighborhood of $I^2$.

Comment: @Max What "old atlas"? Apart from open subsets, you can't take an atlas of a manifold $M$ and "restrict" it to some subset $X \subset M$ and obtain something meaningful... (Not sure what the other notion you define has to do with anything.) I think I've spent enough time arguing about this.

Comment: Indeed, hence my answer. You can obtain in that way an atlas for a manifold with corners, but not a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks! I was thinking of the overlapping maps, but I've seen they are clearly smooth (they are in fact the same ones as the ones in the disk) so I'm convinced.

Answer (score 1):

A manifold with boundary has charts to a half-space. However, near the corners of $I^2$, the natural charts go to a corner space due to the corners. So it is a topological 2-manifold with boundary (after all, it is homeomorphic to the closed disk), but not a smooth 2-manifold with boundary.

Another convenient way to spot it is that the boundary of a manifold with boundary has to be a manifold (without boundary!), but the boundary of $I^2$ has "bad points," which may not be smoothly parameterized.

Comment: could you explicit charts for $[0,1]$ be a manifold?

Comment: But it **is** a smooth $2$-manifold with boundary! More precisely, the topological space $[0,1]^2$ can be given charts that make it into an smooth manifold with boundary. It's not a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$, though. With enough effort I could give you charts for $\partial [0,1]^2$ if you want, by writing down an explicit homeomorphism with $S^1$.

Comment: well, near $0$, you are already an open set in the canonical half-space. Near $1$, you just have to map $(1-\epsilon,1]$ to, say, $[0,\epsilon)$ smoothly.

Comment: It's true you can endow it with a smooth structure, by passing through that homeomorphism, but that's not the same as being a smooth manifold.

Comment: Please define what "being a smooth manifold" is, then.

Comment: A smooth manifold carries an atlas (or, inherits one as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: "A smooth manifold carries an atlas (**or, inherits one as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$**)" You have a strange definition of "smooth manifold", and one that no one uses... Rather, you are talking about a **sub**manifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and indeed $[0,1]^2$ is not an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Definition

Comment: Consider the fact that there are many manifolds homeomorphic, but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$. You can't unambiguously assign a smooth structure to a topological space by passing through a homeomorphism in general. You really need the fixed data of an atlas.

Comment: Let me try something else. How do you make $\mathbb{CP}^n$ into a manifold with your definition that something has to be embedded in some $\mathbb{R}^N$ to become a manifold? It's not naturally embedded into any $\mathbb{R}^N$. You have to fix an embedding, and different embeddings will give you different atlases. Same for your exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$, they can be embedded into some $\mathbb{R}^N$ by Whitney's theorem (not into $\mathbb{R}^4$ obviously). But this isn't how their manifold structure is *defined*...

Comment: I was only pointing out that for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can take the smooth structure to be implicit. At any rate, one could be happy to define manifolds as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since as you say every abstract manifold does arise this way (up to diffeomorphism).

Comment: Guillemin and Pollack do this, for example.

Comment: Incidently, what seems to have been lost in this comment stream is that there is a difference between manifolds with boundary in the "differentiable" category (which is what is being discussed here), and manifolds with boundary in the "topological" category. In the topological category, $[0,1]^2$ **is** a submanifold-with-boundary of $\mathbb{R}^2$.