# There is no diffeomorphism between one quadrant in the plane and the half plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I am trying to prove rigourosly that the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]\subset \mathbb R^2$ is not a differentiable manifold with boundary (I've searched for a rigouros proof, but haven't found anyone) Corners are obviously the problem, so it is reduced to check that otherwise, there would be some open subset around, for example, $(0,0)$, diffeomorphic to $H = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : y \geq 0\}$. How can I prove easily that $Q = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x\geq 0, y\geq 0 \}$ is not diffeomorphic to $H$? Any hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the image of $\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ under a diffeomorphism?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820069/10014 is very related.

Comment: Please, *do not* delete posts after someone took the time to answer it. Posts in the site are meant to help both the original poster and future visitors in the site.

Answer (score 4):

Show that if $\sigma$, $\tau:[0,1)$ are two curves smooth curves in a manifold $M$ such that $\sigma(0)=\tau(0)$ and with the two vectors $\sigma'(0)$ and $\tau'(0)$ linearly independent in $T_{\sigma(0)}M$, and $\phi:M\to N$ is a diffeomorphism, then $(\phi\circ\tau)'(0)$ and $(\phi\circ\sigma)'(0)$ are linearly independent vectors in $T_{\phi(\sigma(0))}(N)$$.

Then find two curves in the first quadrant such that you reach a contradition if the first quadrant were diffeomorphic to a half plane.

Comment: Thank you very much. Altough the first part is very clear to me, I don't see how to reach a contradiction, as you explain in the second paragraph

Comment: In the first quadrant there are two curves that start out from the vertex which stare at you in the face!

Comment: (You will need to use the fact that the vertex of the first quadrant cannot be sent to a point in the interior of the halfplane)

Comment: Well, taking $\varphi:t\mapsto (t,0)$ and $\tau:t\mapsto (0,t)$, $\phi \circ \sigma$ and $\phi\circ \tau$ are smooth curves in the half plane, but don't see how to reach the contradiction.

Comment: Where can the image of $\phi\circ\sigma$ be in the halfplane?

Comment: A diffeomorphism is a homeomorphism, so it must map points in the boundary of the first quadrant to points in the boundary of the halfplane.

Comment: Okay, soy $\phi\circ\sigma$ needs to be in $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$, and the same for $\phi\circ\tau$, then its derivatives are not linearly independent

Comment: Now you see what I wanted you to see.