# Is the surface of a cube a 2-dimensional differentiable manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Is the surface of a cube $[0,1]^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ a 2-dimensional differentiable manifold (it is obviously a topological manifold)? Just assume the topology is Euclidean topology please. It seems that the 8 corners of the cube are singularities by intuition. This problem may be easy for you, however I find it hard to prove (or disprove)  by the definition of differentiable manifold. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820069/10014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at least not in the sense that you want.

If it *were* a manifold, then by the classification theorem for compact 2-manifolds, it'd have to be diffeomorphic to a sphere. So the question then becomes

> Is there an embedding $f$ of the sphere in 3-space whose image is exactly the unit cube?

If there were, then (with a little bit of isotopy in the domain sphere) we could assume that $f(0, 1, 0) = (0, 1, 0)$ and $f(1, 0, 0) = (1, 0, 0)$, i.e., that the north pole and the "east pole" of the cube get transformed into the center of the top of the cube  and the center of the "east" face of the cube, respectively.

Now consider the arc $c$ defined by
$$
t\mapsto (\sin t, \cos t, 0)
$$
for $0 \le t \le \pi/2$. That's a smooth path on the sphere (it's part of a line of longitude!), so $b = f \circ c$ must be a smooth path on the cube.

Because the cube with all its edges and vertices removed has six connected components, with the north and east points in different components, but the interval is connected, we see that the path $b$ must meet the set of edges and vertices at some point $P$. Let's say that $$
b(t_0) = P
$$
where $t_0$ is neither $0$ nor $\pi/2$, i.e., it's in the interior of the domain of $b$.

What is $b'(t_0)?$

On the one hand, it's $f'(c(t_0)) c'(t_0)$, and must therefore be nonzero, because $f$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. On the other hand, it has to be a "tangent vector" at $b(t_0)$, a point on the edge of the cube. That pretty much requires that it lie in the direction of the edge. So a smooth curve from the north to the east pole of the sphere *could* become a smooth curve from the north to the east "pole" of the cube by heading towards an edge, running along the edge, and continuing off the edges into the eastern face.

But now take another unit arc $d$ that meets $c$ orthogonally at $c(t_0)$, and let's say $d(t_0) = c(t_0)$ by a shift of parameter if necessary.

Let $a(t) = f(d(t))$. What's $a'(t_0)$? It's got to be tangent to the cube at $a(t_0) = P$, and it's got to be *nonzero* and linearly independent from $b'(t_0)$, because $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

So: take any arc on the cube that crosses an edge transversally, and with nonzero speed at the crossing. Can that arc be differentiable at the crossing? No. For just before crossing, the curve lies in (say) the north face, and hence has a tangent orthogonal to $(0,1,0)$; just after the crossing, it lies in the east face, and has a tangent orthogonal to $(1,0,0)$. Hence the tangent at the crossing must be orthogonal to both, and thus be in the direction of $(0,0,1)$. But that makes it NOT linearly independent from $b'(t_0)$. And that's a contradiction.

I've been a little sloppy here, talking about "just before the crossing" and "just after the crossing"...how do I know that for some small time before $t_0$ we have $a(t)$ is on the "north face" and that for some small time after, it's on the "east face"? Answer: a little bit of careful analysis, and the fact that every nonconstant curve is well approximated by its tangent locally.

But the gist here is clear: the tangent plane to $S^2$ at $c(t_0)$ would have to be transformed, by $f'$, isomorphically to a tangent plane to the cube along one of the edges. But that "tangent plane" can really only contain the edge itself, hence is 1-dimensional, and you've got a contradiction.

Comment: This shows that the surface of the cube doesn't admit a structure of differentiable manifold compatible with the differentiable structure of the ambient space $\mathbb R^3$. I think that's what the OP meant to ask, but it's not explicit in the question. The cube surface does have a structure of differentiable manifold (if you don't care about the ambient space); just transport the standard differentiable structure of the sphere along any homeomorphism to the cube surface.

Comment: Completely agree. I took OP's "Just assume the topology is Euclidean topology please" to mean "and assume the differentiable structure is the one inherited from the embedding as well." I was going to write down an explicit differentiable homeomorphism from the unit circle to the unit square, and point out that it was not a diffeo because at the four "corner points" the map had an inverse, but the derivative of the inverse was undefined, like $x \mapsto x^3$ on the reals. But I ran out of energy. :)